# Write the integer 0 to file, read the file, increment integer to 10, and arrange it through the child and parent process

Tags: c, shell, parent-child, parent, increment

This has obviously been done before, but the trouble with this code is that it simply is not incrementing, but it is doing everything else fine. I want to have it where the output of the file reads the integer that the loop is going up to. Instead, it gets stuck at 0. I need some help. I am writing this in C. Here is my code:

assignment9.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "tellwait.h"

void err_sys(const char* message);

int main(void){
    FILE *filepoint;
    int* zero = 0;
    int val;
    char* buffer[180];
    pid_t pid;
    filepoint = fopen("testfile.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(filepoint, "%d", zero); 
    TELL_WAIT();
    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        err_sys("fork error");
    }
    else if (pid == 0)  //child
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            WAIT_PARENT();
            filepoint = fopen("testfile.txt", "w+");
            fread(buffer, sizeof(zero), 1, filepoint);
            // increment
            val = atoi(buffer[0]);
            val++;
            // use fprintf to write back to file
            //printf("Current amount: %d, Child Process\n", zero);
            printf("%d\n", val);
            fprintf(filepoint, "%d", val); 
            TELL_PARENT(pid);

        }
    }
    else {    //parent
        int i;          
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            filepoint = fopen("testfile.txt", "w+");
            fread(buffer, sizeof(zero), 1, filepoint);
            // increment
            val = atoi(buffer[0]);
            val++;
            // use fprintf to write back to file
            //printf("Current amount: %d, Parent Process\n", zero);
            printf("%d\n", val);
            fprintf(filepoint, "%d", val);
            TELL_CHILD(pid);
            WAIT_CHILD();
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void err_sys(const char* message)
{
    printf("%s\n", message);
    exit(0);
}
```

tellwait.h:

```
#ifndef _TELL_WAIT_H
#define _TELL_WAIT_H

void    TELL_WAIT(void); /* parent/child from {Sec race_conditions} */
void    TELL_PARENT(pid_t);
void    TELL_CHILD(pid_t);
void    WAIT_PARENT(void);
void    WAIT_CHILD(void);

#endif
```

tellwait.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void err_sys (const char* message);

static volatile sig_atomic_t sigflag; /* set nonzero by sig handler */
static sigset_t newmask, oldmask, zeromask;

static void sig_usr(int signo)  /* one signal handler for SIGUSR1 and     SIGUSR2 */
{
   sigflag = 1;
}

void TELL_WAIT(void)
{
   if (signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr) == SIG_ERR)
       err_sys("signal(SIGUSR1) error");
   if (signal(SIGUSR2, sig_usr) == SIG_ERR)
       err_sys("signal(SIGUSR2) error");
   sigemptyset(&zeromask);
   sigemptyset(&newmask);
   sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);
   sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR2);

   /* Block SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2, and save current signal mask */
   if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask) < 0)
       err_sys("SIG_BLOCK error");
   }

void TELL_PARENT(pid_t pid)
{
   kill(pid, SIGUSR2);      /* tell parent we're done */
}

void WAIT_PARENT(void)
{
   while (sigflag == 0)
       sigsuspend(&zeromask);   /* and wait for parent */
   sigflag = 0;

   /* Reset signal mask to original value */
   if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
       err_sys("SIG_SETMASK error");
}

void TELL_CHILD(pid_t pid)
{
   kill(pid, SIGUSR1);          /* tell child we're done */
}

void WAIT_CHILD(void)
{
   while (sigflag == 0)
      sigsuspend(&zeromask);    /* and wait for child */
   sigflag = 0;

   /* Reset signal mask to original value */
   if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
      err_sys("SIG_SETMASK error");
}
```

The file output for testfile.txt is 10, while the test console output I am attempting to get is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

May you please help me?

Comment: lets start with tellwait.c does not compile because the tellwait.h file contains references to pid_t and does not contain the required #include <sys/types.h> before the references to pid_t in the header file  and the tellwait.h file needs to be included in the tellwait.c file

Comment: this line: 'int* zero = 0;' and this line: 'fprintf(filepoint, "%d", zero); ' do not match as 'zero' is a pointer to integer (and that pointer contains 0 (should be NULL)  and %d is expecting an integer parameter, not a pointer to integer parameter.  so the compilation fails.  There are a bunch of other problems. among the three files.  Please compile with all warnings enabled (for gcc, at least use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  then fix the problems (warnings also need to be fixed) then please re-post the code.

Comment: the tellwait.c file needs to #include <sys/signal.h> so the signal functions and #defines are available for use in the program and if using gcc parameter -std=c99 then before #include <stdlib.h> insert '#define _GNU_SOURCE'   The function: sig_usr() has a parameter that is not used.  that causes the compiler to raise a warning that needs to be fixed.

Comment: the returned value from fopen(0, fread(),  all need to be checked to assure the operation was successful.  this line: ' exit(0);' in function: err_sys() is indicating that no error occurred when an error did occur,  suggest 'exit(1)' or better yet: 'exit( EXIT_FAILURE );'

Comment: this line: 'val = atoi(buffer[0]);' is only converting the first byte of the buffer from ascii to int.  Since 4 bytes were read via: 'fread(buffer, sizeof(zero), 1, filepoint);' (which probably is not correct as an ascii number can be ~11bytes long)  suggest: 'val = atoi( buffer );

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the code, like: 10,  180, etc.  there should be a #define MEANINGFUL_NAME (10)  kind of statements near the top of the code and the 'magic' numbers replaced with the #define names  In general, #define names are written in all caps, separated by underscores and function names are all lower case or 'lower-camel case'

Comment: the parent and child processing on the file testfile.txt will be clobbering each others output,  Probably not what you want.

Comment: this line: 'char* buffer[180];' is declaring an array of 180 pointers to char.  I suspect that what was actually wanted was 'char buffer[180];' to declare an array of 180 characters.